# Hyperledger composer Rest API filter not working for asset

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to execute Rest API using following filter

`api/Commodity?filter={"where":{"owner":"resource:org.example.mynetwork.Trader%231"},%20"include":"resolve"}`

but getting following error -

`{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb","code":2,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}},"details":"error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb","stack":"Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb\n    at new createStatusError (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)\n    at /home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15"}}`

Kindly suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the response is here `Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb`

This says that your fabric is configured to use the inbuilt leveldb system for storing the world state. Because of this you cannot perform any type of query on it, and that includes rest filters.

You need to change your fabric setup to use couchdb as the world state store instead.

Fabric documentation can be found here about building fabric networks and on this page there is a specific section about enabling couchdb.
see https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html

Comment: But filter is working fine if it is like - api/Commodity?filter={"where":{"quantity":"9532"},%20"include":"resolve"} . The problem is in the case where we have value for relation like "resource:org.example.mynetwork.Trader%231"

Comment: The above error you posted is becuase your fabric is using leveldb and not couchdb. To make it work you need to move to using couchdb.